# Django-registration setup without password

Tags: django, authentication, registration, django-registration

I am trying to make a website, where people only put their email addresses and they are logged in with cookies and all. At a later stage, i will ask them provide password and names, but NO username will be used. I am trying to do this with django-registraition, but i get errors and i have a few problems.

First to disable usernames as a login feature, i put str(time()) instead of username - i was looking for something that will change every time.

However, when I skip the authentication (which i currently don't need) i get error:

```
'RegistrationProfile' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

Alternatively, i can leave the authentication but then i don't know how to authenticate it only with email and no password. Also, i don't know how to make the next line work:

```
auth.login(request, ProfileUser)
```

If anyone can get me out of here, it would be awesome. Here is some code:

my form Class:

```
class RegistrationFormCustom(forms.Form):
email = forms.EmailField()
def do_save(self):
    new_u = User(username=str(time()),email= self.cleaned_data.get('email'),)
    new_u.save()
    new_p = Profile.objects.create_profile(new_u)
    new_p.save()
    return new_p
```

my view:

```
def registerCustom(request, backend, success_url=None, form_class=None,
         disallowed_url='registration_disallowed',
         template_name='registration/registration_form.html',
         extra_context=None,
     initial={}):

form = RegistrationFormCustom(initial=initial)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationFormCustom(initial=initial, data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        profile = form.do_save()
        profile = auth.authenticate(username = profile.user.email, password = form.cleaned_data.get('pass1'))
        print(profile)
        auth.login(request, profile)
        return redirect('/')

    else:
        pass

return render_jinja(request, 'registration/registration_form.html',
        type="register",
        form = form
        )
```

and i will post any other snipped required happily

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the `'RegistrationProfile' object has no attribute 'backend'` error because the user is not yet authenticated. To log someone in, you have to call the `authenticate` method first, which requires a password. So, what you can do instead, is this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import load_backend, login, logout
from django.conf import settings

def _login_user(request, user):
    """
    Log in a user without requiring credentials (using ``login`` from
    ``django.contrib.auth``, first finding a matching backend).

    """
    if not hasattr(user, 'backend'):
        for backend in settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS:
            if user == load_backend(backend).get_user(user.pk):
                user.backend = backend
                break
    if hasattr(user, 'backend'):
        return login(request, user)
```

Then, to log someone in, just call the `_login_user` function with the request and `User` model. (This will be `profile.user` in your case, probably) Do this instead of calling `auth.login`. I'm not sure on how you're going to determine whether this is a valid user or not, without a password or username, but I'll leave that to you. If you still have trouble, let me know.

**Short Explanation:**

What basically happens here is that Django requires a user to be authenticated in order to be logged in via the `login` function. That authentication is usually done by the `authenticate` function, which requires a username and password, and checks whether the supplied password matches the hashed version in the database. If it does, it adds an authentication backend to the `User` model.

So, since you don't have a password and username, you just have to write your own method for adding the authentication backend to the `User` model. And that's what my `_login_user`) function does - if the user is already authenticated, it just calls `login`, otherwise, it first adds the default backend to the `User` model, without checking for a correct username and password (like `authenticate` does).

Comment: Hey, you are my code fairy. With a few tweaks it actually did the job. Do you think you can explain it with one sentence? I just don't seem to be able to understand what's going on here. I also searched for explanation of what 'backend' is, but couldn't find that either

Comment: I added a short explanation, hopefully that helps a bit. These things are a bit of a dark art in Django, but I'm glad I got you a bit further along the way.

Comment: awesome. can i just ask you what is backend and what does it contain?

Comment: @mgPepe: to quote the Django docs, `An authentication backend is a class that implements two methods: get_user(user_id) and authenticate(**credentials).` - [Authentication Backends](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend)

Answer (score 0):

For others reading this thread, I got a similar error message when I was using User.objects.create() instead of User.objects.create_user().  Basically, the first method was setting a clear password whereas create_user encrypts the password.  Clear passwords will fail to authenticate.  Check your database, if you have passwords set in the clear, then it's likely you need to use create_user() instead.

The author's request could be fixed by simply setting a default user and password using create_user() instead of just user.save().

Answer (score 0):

You can create a known password (put it in settings.py ) and use that as though the user entered it. Create the user with this and authenticate the user with this.