# Wagtail: Create registration page with e-mail and verify

Tags: python, wagtail

How could I add a link to a page with SignIn via e-mail and then send a verification e-mail? I want to add a user to Wagtail, create group, site with name of the user. Why Wagtail doesn't have a module for that membership site?

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is a bit old but it should be updated.  Wagtail makes use of django's in-built auth views.

> Wagtail uses Django’s standard django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView
>   view here, and so the context variables available on the template are
>   as detailed in Django's login view documentation.

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.6.1/advanced_topics/privacy.html#setting-up-a-login-page

That said, it should be pretty straight forward.  Set up auth as you normally would for a django project, and make your own templates.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#using-the-django-authentication-system

Answer (score 0):

Using [Django-registration](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration) is posible as explained here:
[Django-registration setup without password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5843319/3186190)

Comment: Your answer is not Wagtail-specific. I am here because was googling how to customize/create Wagtail sign up. I think that he needs to implement some Custom user model, but do not know how to do this.